Session doesn't show value on changing routes
Express session doesn't show value on changing routes. Here in '/login' route it shows req.session.user data, but in '/connect' it shows req.session.user is undefined
Here is the code
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import userHelpers from './helpers/userHelpers.js';
import db from './config/connection.js';
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo';

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// Session configuration
app.use(session({
    secret: "Key",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongoUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/connect-app' }),
    cookie: { maxAge: 6000000 }
}));

// Connect to the database
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error in connection");
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to database");
    }
});

// Routes

app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    await userHelpers.signupUser(data).then((info) => {
        console.log("User created:", info);
        res.json({ valid: true });
    });
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    userHelpers.loginUser(data).then((info) => {
        if (info) {
            req.session.user = { info };
            req.session.save();
            console.log("Login session :", req.session.user);
            res.json({ valid: true, userInfo: { info } });
        } else {
            console.log("User not found");
            res.json({ valid: false });
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error:", err);
        res.json({ valid: false });
    });
});

app.get('/connect', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Connect session:", req.session.user);
    if (req.session.user) {
        const user = req.session.user;
        console.log("USER:", user);
        return res.json({ valid: true, userInfo: user.info.email });
    } else {
        return res.json({ valid: false });
    }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server is running');
});


/login
const HandleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login', { email, password }, {withCredentials:true, credentials: 'include'}).then((result) => {
            if(result.data.valid)
                navigate('/connect')
            else
                navigate('/login')
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

/connect
useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/connect').then((response)=>{
            console.log(response.data)
        })
    })

I was trying to pass user data in session from '/login' to '/connect' route to display the username and other details. And I ended up in this error.

What is the client here?  Is it requests made from Javascript in the browser?  The usual issue for this type of thing is that the client isn't preserving or passing the session cookie so express-session has to make a new empty session.  Please show client making these requests.

@jfriend00 I have updated the code with client requests. Kindly check it.

If these axios calls to http://localhost:3001/connect are a different port than the web page itself, then you may need to add the withCredentials: true option to your axios.get() and axios.post() calls.  See here for more discussion of that option.  This tells axios to send the cookies with the request.

@jfriend00  I added withCredentials:true option on every axios call. But now it shows axios error, request failed with status code 500. ERR_BAD_REPONSE on console.

I would assume that means one of your server routes is generating a 500 response.  You will have to debug which route that is and why it's doing that.

Thanks man! I was trying to solve this error. And finally I did it. Your suggestions helped me a lot.!
